# Hermiticity of 2d free fermion kinetic term

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, fermions

The action of a 2d free fermion can be written as:
$$S=\frac{1} {8\pi} \int dz^2(\psi \bar{\partial} \psi +\bar{\psi}\partial \bar{\psi})$$
[see for example https://www.nikhef.nl/~t58/CFT.pdf or any of the big CFT books.] How can you check the Hermiticity of this kinetic term? Under conjugation the fermions switch position: $(\bar{\partial}\psi)  \psi +(\partial \bar{\psi})\bar{\psi}$, which we can move to its normal position by partial integration: $-\psi \bar{\partial} \psi -\bar{\psi}\partial \bar{\psi}$.

Thus I get a minus sigh where I don't expect one... so my question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which book & page?

Comment: Is there any reason for the action to be Hermitian?

Comment: This may be an artifact of Euclidean metric. I would suggest to switch back to Minkowski spacetime (should give the missing $i$ in front of the action), see if it works there, and then carefully formulate the hermiticity requirement for the action in the Euclidean formulation. And, of course, inform us about the results :)